# sql - query which extracts all records but only the most recent record of a duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server

What query I need which extracts all records but only the most recent record of a duplicate?

I have this query for records of duplicates:

```
    $SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM ['Duplicate Data$'] t1
WHERE Name in
(
    SELECT Name
    FROM ['Duplicate Data$']
    GROUP BY Name
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
)
ORDER BY Name$
```

And this for most recent record:

```
$SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM  ['Duplicate Data$'] t1
WHERE Date = (SELECT max(Date) FROM ['Duplicate Data$'] WHERE t1.Name =['Duplicate Data$'].Name)
ORDER BY Date DESC$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.* 
FROM ['Duplicate Data$'] t1
JOIN (
  SELECT Name, MAX(DATE) AS [MaxDate]
  FROM ['Duplicate Data$']
  GROUP BY Name
  HAVING COUNT(*)>1
) AS D
ON D.Name = T1.Name 
AND D.MaxDate = T1.Date
ORDER BY T1.Name
```